# Merge 2 retvals of getPerspectiveTransform python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to merge the retvals of `getPerspectiveTransform` so what I did is something like this:

```
for cord in cord_list:
   M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(cord,pts2)
   Ms.append(M)
   if(len(Ms)==2):
      newM = np.multiply(Ms[0],Ms[1])
      dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,newM,(300,300))
```

but the image after applying transformation using `warpPerspective` is blank. It works fine for a single image but when I try to multiply (merge) the perspective matrices it gives me a blank image. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order of multiplication of the Perspective matrices worked.

```
newM = np.multiply(Ms[1],Ms[0])

dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img,newM,(300,300))
```

and an image was found.